# Single Word Without Quotes and Multiple Words Within Quotes

Tags: regex, vba

I am using VBA and Access to clean up the Rich Text. I don't mind colors, bold, underline, but I want to force the font style and size.

```vb
With objRegEx
    .Global = True
    'Replace font size
    .Pattern = "size=[0-9]"
    strText = .Replace(strText, " size=" & nSize)
    'Replace font face
    .Pattern = "face=([""'])(?:[\r\n]*(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1"
    strText = .Replace(strText, "face=" & strFont)
End With
```

It only works if the font is encased in quotes. This doesn't work for single-word-named fonts.

I need to match

```
font="Times New Roman"
font='Times New Roman'
font=Calibri
```

Comment: That can be done with `.Pattern = "face=(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|\S+)"`. Also, `.Pattern = "size=[0-9]"` must be `.Pattern = "size=[0-9]+"`, I think.

Comment: Strange. Not appearing to work in regex101, but works in my VBA! Thanks!

Comment: Because in VBA, these are string literals where you need to double the `"`s inside. At regex101, you need to use literal string patterns, i.e. if you need to match a `"`, use `"`, and not `""`. AND please make sure you use `font` or `face` - I am not sure what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```vb
.Pattern = "size=[0-9]+"
```

Here, `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits.

To solve the main problem you can use

```vb
.Pattern = "face=(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|\S+)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7OE2VV/2). *Details*:

- `face=` - a string
- `(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\S+)` - a non-capturing group matching

  - `"[^"]*"|` - `"`, then any zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char, or
  - `'[^']*'|` - `'`, then any zero or more chars other than `'` and then a `'` char, or
  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars